# Where do I pass immigration when transferring in Canada?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

I'm traveling from Seoul, to destination in Canada. I have a transfer in Vancouver, where do I pass the immigration&custom? Vancouver? Final destination?

Comment: Short answer: wherever the directional signs in the airport tell you to.

Comment: @phoog of course I was told to pass CIQ before making connection when I was checking in @ Airlines, that's not the answer I would expect, because the point of the question here is that I want to know the fact before going to the airport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will pass immigration and customs at the first Canadian airport that you arrive at which would be Vancouver.